# Feature selection drastically decreases accuracy

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, particle-swarm

Ive been playing around with Pyswarms specifically with discrete.binaryPSO to perform feature selection as it is an optimisation technique that helps perform feature subset selection to improve classifier performance. (https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/development/examples/feature_subset_selection.html)<- link to pyswarms.

My dataset is based on text data with a corresponding label(identified in 1’s and 0’s). Upon preprocessing, i incorporated countvectorizer and tfidftransformer to the text data.

However a simple machine learning classifier using sklearn predicts a much higher accuracy in comparison to incorporating pyswarms. No matter what dataset i use, pre-processing techniques and functions i add when incorporating discrete.binarypso my accuracy, precision and recall is lower than a simple machine learning classification using SKlearn.

My code is attached below any help on the situation is appreciated:

```
# Create an instance of the classifier
classifier = LogisticRegression()
# Define objective function


# Define objective function
def f_per_particle(m, alpha):

    total_features = training_data.shape[1]
    # Get the subset of the features from the binary mask
    if np.count_nonzero(m) == 0:
        X_subset = training_data
    else:
        X_subset = training_data[:,m==1]
    # Perform classification and store performance in P
    classifier.fit(X_subset, y_train)
    P = (classifier.predict(X_subset) == y_train).mean()
    # Compute for the objective function
    j = (alpha * (1.0 - P)
        + (1.0 - alpha) * (1 - (X_subset.shape[1] / total_features)))

    return j

def f(x, alpha=0.88):
    """Higher-level method to do classification in the
    whole swarm.

    Inputs
    ------
    x: numpy.ndarray of shape (n_particles, dimensions)
        The swarm that will perform the search

    Returns
    -------
    numpy.ndarray of shape (n_particles, )
        The computed loss for each particle
    """
    n_particles = x.shape[0]
    j = [f_per_particle(x[i], alpha) for i in range(n_particles)]
    return np.array(j)


options = {'c1':0.5, 'c2': 0.5,'w':0.9,'k': 10,'p':2}
# Call instance of PSO
dimensions = training_data.shape[1] # dimensions should be the number of features
optimizer = ps.discrete.BinaryPSO(n_particles=10, dimensions=dimensions, options=options)

# Perform optimization
cost, pos = optimizer.optimize(f, iters=10)

print('selected features = ' + str(sum((pos == 1)*1)) + '/' + str(len(pos)))
classifier.fit(training_data, y_train)
print('accuracy before FS = ' + str(accuracy_score(y_test, classifier.predict(testing_data), normalize = True)*100))
X_subset = training_data[:,pos==1]
classifier.fit(X_subset, y_train)
print('accuracy after FS = ' + str(accuracy_score(y_test, classifier.predict(testing_data[:,pos==1]), normalize = True)*100))
```

Comment: I am no expert on algorithm pyswarm uses, but I can tell you that it is not necessary that feature selection algorithm produces better results, they also produce poor results. It completely depends on dataset. If feature selection is not working good for you, go with all the features or try a different algorithm

Comment: I understand that completely. Honestly I've tried different datasets as well as incorporating different classification techniques to increase the accuracy using pyswarms. Ive looked at certain github codes as well,  that incorporate pyswarms on datasets thats arent text based and it has largely increased the accuracy of them. Hence i was wondering maybe im doing something wrong since in working with text based data

Answer (score 0):

Since feature selection is not yielding better performance, I would recommend to use all the features in the machine learning model and see the impact of each feature. You may find
[https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html[SHAP][1]](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html%5BSHAP%5D%5B1%5D)
to be helpful for explaining the output and then look at the significance of each feature for this purpose.